# Use variable from one method to another method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop

I am duplicating a configuration variable wherever I am Using. I want to make that common in one method and use that method's variable across the project.

**common.ts**

```
    Notification(){

    User.findOne({ email: data.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {

            if (user.device_info[0].platform == 'Android') {

                var Notification_config = new SNS({
                    platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.ANDROID,
                    accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
                    secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
                    region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
                    platformApplicationArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:XXXXXXXX:app/GCM/Test',
                });
                console.log("Andriod");
            }
            else {
                console.log("iOS");
                var Notification_config = new SNS({
                    platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.IOS,
                    accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
                    secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
                    region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
                    platformApplicationArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:XXXXXX:app/APNS_SANDBOX/Test',
                    sandbox: true
                });
            }
        })
 }
```

**abc.ts**

```
  Notification_config.addUser('dev_token', JSON.stringify({
      some: 'extra data'
  }), function (err, endpointArn) {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
      // Send a simple String or data to the client
      Notification_config.sendMessage(endpointArn, ` sent you a request`, function (err, messageId) {
          if (err) {
             res.send(err)
          }
          req; res;
          console.log('Message sent, ID was: ' + messageId);
      });
```

What I tried

```
function push_notification(email) {
    User.findOne({
        email: email
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            if (data.device_info[0].platform == 'Android') {
                var platform = SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.ANDROID;
                var arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXX:app/GCM/Test'
                //console.log("Andriod");
            } else {
                var platform = SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.IOS;
                var arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXX:app/APNS_SANDBOX/Test'
                //console.log("iOS");
            }

            var Notification_config = new SNS({
                platform: platform,
                accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
                secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
                region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
                platformApplicationArn: arn,
                sandbox: true
            });
        }
        return Notification_config;
    });

}

export default push_notification;
```

I want the variable `Notification_config` from `common.ts` to be used in `abc.ts`. I have tried to return the `Notification_config` to method and `export default Notification` in common.ts and import it in abc.ts but It couldn't find the variable. Can someone help me out.

Comment: "I tried ..." please show that try.

Comment: Please check the updated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Like so:

**common.ts**

```
export default function Notification(data:any){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       User.findOne({ email: data.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
        }
        else {
         if (user.device_info[0].platform == 'Android') {

            var Notification_config = new SNS({
                platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.ANDROID,
                accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
                secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
                region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
                platformApplicationArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:XXXXXXXX:app/GCM/Test',
            });
            console.log("Andriod");
            resolve(Notification_config);
         }
         else {
            console.log("iOS");
            var Notification_config = new SNS({
                platform: SNS.SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS.IOS,
                accessKeyId: cache.get('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'),
                secretAccessKey: cache.get('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY'),
                region: cache.get('AMAZON_REGION'),
                platformApplicationArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:XXXXXX:app/APNS_SANDBOX/Test',
                sandbox: true
            });
            resolve(Notification_config);
        }
      })
    })
}
```

**abc.ts**

```
import Notification from './common';

Notification(data).then(function (Notification_config) {
    // Now you have access to 'Notification_config'
})
```

Comment: When I console i could get the value but I couldn't use `Notification_config.addUser('dev_token', JSON.stringify({` in `abc.ts` I am getting `Object is of type 'unknown'`

Comment: With the old code just `Notification(data).then(function (Notification_config:any)` works!!